# Typed dependencies for the Stanford parser

Tags: java, parsing, stanford-nlp

The typed dependencies given by [Stanford parser online](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/) and the dependencies generated by the sourcecode given aren't same.

The versions of source codes available in Stanford website does not generate abbrev, possessive and poss tags.

Which version of Stanford parser to use for generating these tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are the same.  The answer was that you had to invoke the parser in a way that would cause tokenization of the input.  Some examples are:

```
LexicalizedParser lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel("edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz");
String sent = "This is one last test!";
lp.apply(sent).pennPrint();
```

or in a more complex scenario:

```
TreebankLanguagePack tlp = lp.getOp().langpack();
Tokenizer<? extends HasWord> toke = tlp.getTokenizerFactory().getTokenizer(new StringReader(sent));
List<? extends HasWord> sentence = toke.tokenize();
lp.apply(sentence);
```

Comment: What class is `tlp` variable and how to create it?

Comment: TreebankLanguagePack.  Sorry, that was missing.  I made an edit, adding a line to initialize it.